# Question about second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators, second-quantization

I've spent awhile trying to understand where this equality I marked with '?' may come from. If $\hat{o}$ is just the $O_1$ operator in a special basis then I've no idea where from $n_\lambda$ could make it's appearance.

[image: Page from Atland's Condensed Matter ...]

Page from Atland's Condensed Matter Field Theory, Second Edition p.47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$o_{\lambda_i}$ is the expectation value of $\hat{o}$ for a single particle in state $\lambda_i$.  If you have $n_{\lambda_i}$ particles in that state, you need to multiply $o_{\lambda_i} n_{\lambda_i}$ to get the value for $\hat{O}_1$, since this operator sums over the particles.